# How to open a local html file, not with file:// but with a web server like http://localhost:8080/VideoUsingWebComponents/index.html

Tags: html, web, server, localhost

[I am not able to follow this .png file,posted for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbaa1.png)

I have a zipped file extracted to the following location,C:\Program Files\WAMP\ht docs\VideoUsingWebComponents, created as per the image file uploaded here.In the folder I am supposed to open the index.html file with a web server, on simply clicking on the html file the browser opens with file:///C:/Program%20Files/WAMP/ht%20docs/VideoUsingWebComponents/index.html,
I want it to open with http://localhost:8080...as instructed in the uploaded image, so I tried changing the above link like this,
http://localhost:8080/C:/Program%20Files/WAMP/ht%20docs/VideoUsingWebComponents/index.html, but localhost refused to connect.
I am using a windows pc , the image shown here is of a Mac.Please help to open index.html file with a web server.
Thank you

Comment: Please format your question better.  It is confusing.  Have you installed a web server?  You will not be able to access `localhost:8080` unless you have a web server running.

Answer (score 1):

localhost:8080 is a port that is used by any server that runs on your computer.

But usually you need to install such a server on your own.

Mozilla has an article explaining everything in detail - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server

And this guy explains things in even more simplified way on how to install server on all platforms, just scroll to windows section - https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-web-server-all-platforms/

Hope both of these links help you!

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with a built-in server which you can directly invoke:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```